# Open image from JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using [JSQMesssagesViewController](http://www.jessesquires.com/JSQMessagesViewController/) to build a messaging app. I can now send an image using this, but would like to tap the image to open in full screen. This functionality would be similar to the standard messaging application that allows you to tap on an image "bubble", and pinch to zoom in and out. Has anyone had experience doing this with JSQMessagesViewController? Thanks to those who who can lend assistance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSQmessage does not handle that but you can add this functionality in this method and by using zoomPopup class:

```
- (void)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JSQMessage *message = [self.messageModelData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (message.isMediaMessage) {
        id<JSQMessageMediaData> mediaItem = message.media;

        if ([mediaItem isKindOfClass:[JSQPhotoMediaItem class]]) {

            NSLog(@"Tapped photo message bubble!");

            JSQPhotoMediaItem *photoItem = (JSQPhotoMediaItem *)mediaItem;
            [self popupImage:photoItem.image];
        }
    }
}

- (void) popupImage: (UIImage*)image
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *topView = window.rootViewController.view;
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    zoomPopup  *popup = [[zoomPopup alloc] initWithMainview:topView andStartRect:CGRectMake(topView.frame.size.width/2, topView.frame.size.height/2, 0, 0)];
    [popup showPopup:imageView];
}
```

and you can see zoomPopup here:
https://github.com/Tintenklecks/zoomPopup

Comment: i am working on JSQMessageView Controller. Please look into this issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/38371995/2522603

Answer (score 12):

SWIFT 3: I found another way without using any other pods/libraries.

1) Add `var selectedImage: UIImage?` on top of your `ChatViewController`.

2) Override the method `didTapMessageBubbleAt`, for example:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAt indexPath: IndexPath!) {
    if let test = self.getImage(indexPath: indexPath) {
        selectedImage = test
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMedia", sender: self)
    }
}
```

3) Add this function to get the image when it's clicked on by the user and return an `UIImage` (will return nil if it's a text message that has been taped on):

```
func getImage(indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIImage? {
        let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
        if message.isMediaMessage == true {
            let mediaItem = message.media
            if mediaItem is JSQPhotoMediaItem {
                let photoItem = mediaItem as! JSQPhotoMediaItem
                if let test: UIImage = photoItem.image {
                    let image = test
                    return image
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

4) Add the segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showMedia" {
            if let pageDeDestination = segue.destination as? ShowMediaViewController {
                pageDeDestination.image = selectedImage!
                } else {
                print("type destination not ok")
            }
        } else {
            print("segue inexistant")
        }
    }
```

5) In the Interface Builder, add a View controller nearby your `chatVC` and add a segue (type `Show`) with `showMedia` as the segue identifier. Add an image view in the new `viewcontroller`.

6) Here is the code of my `ShowMediaViewController`:

```
class ShowMediaViewController: UIViewController {
    var image: UIImage? = nil
    var titreText: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titre: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //titre.text = titreText

        if image != nil {
            imageView.image = image
        } else {
            print("image not found")
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put "Aspect Fit" as a parameter in your image view (in the interface builder) to display correctly the image.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0.1** Hope it helps someone.I have tested this code

I have used following code to show `image` on Full Screen when tapped `Image` on `JSQMessagesViewController`.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let message: JSQMessage? = messages[indexPath.row]
    if message?.isMediaMessage != nil {
        let mediaItem: JSQMessageMediaData? = message?.media
        if (mediaItem is JSQPhotoMediaItem) {
            print("Tapped photo message bubble!")
            let photoItem = mediaItem as? JSQPhotoMediaItem

            let newImageView = UIImageView(image: photoItem?.image)
            newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            newImageView.backgroundColor = .gray
            newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
            newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true // tabBarController exists
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true // default  navigationController
        }
    }
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false 
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview() // This will remove image from full screen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if using with PhotoSlider(https://github.com/nakajijapan/PhotoSlider)

```
// var images = [UIImage]() // puts images of messages here
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAt indexPath: IndexPath!) {
  let index = indexPath.row
  let message = messages[index]
  if message.isMediaMessage {
    if message.media.isKind(of: JSQPhotoMediaItem.self) {
      let photoSlider = PhotoSlider.ViewController(images: images)
      let i = images.index(of: (message.media as! JSQPhotoMediaItem).image)!
      photoSlider.currentPage = i
      photoSlider.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
      photoSlider.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
      present(photoSlider, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```