# JSQMessagesViewController - Send text Message with Attached Images File

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using **JSQMessagesViewController** for sending and receiving messages.It works well for text Messages. **Is it possible to send Text Message with attached Image File using JSQMessagesViewController Framework.**

The attached image file should be shown, when it is clicked on. Something like this.

**Send messages should be shown like this in Message window.**

[image]

**For Sending Photo**

```
- (void)addPhotoMediaMessage
{
   JSQPhotoMediaItem *photoItem = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goldengate"]];
   JSQMessage *photoMessage = [JSQMessage messageWithSenderId:kJSQDemoAvatarIdSquires
                                               displayName:kJSQDemoAvatarDisplayNameSquires
                                                     media:photoItem];
  [self.messages addObject:photoMessage];
}
```

**Sending text Message**

```
- (void)didPressSendButton:(UIButton *)button
       withMessageText:(NSString *)text
              senderId:(NSString *)senderId
     senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName
                  date:(NSDate *)date
{
    [JSQSystemSoundPlayer jsq_playMessageSentSound];
    JSQMessage *message = [JSQMessage messageWithSenderId:senderId
                                          displayName:senderDisplayName
                                                 text:text];
   [self.messages addObject:message];
   [self finishSendingMessageAnimated:YES];
   [self receiveAutoMessage];
}
```

Comment: I dont know Objective C but can write the code in Swift. Would that help?

Comment: can there be multiple files attached to one message?

Comment: ya can be multiple file also. in my case file means uiimage only

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: @utkbansal bro i m converting ur code to objective c .once done let u know

Comment: @utkbansal have u done sample in swift let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117511/discussion-between-imran-and-utkbansal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To accomplish this task you will have to create a **custom cell** and then use that cell in your CollectionView

First of all **subclass the JSQMessage** class to something like following to keep the data for the image urls(attachments) -

```
class ChatMessage: JSQMessage {

    internal var attachments : [NSURL]?

    init(senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!, text: String!, attachments: [NSURL]?) {
        self.attachments = attachments
        super.init(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: date, text: text)
    }

    init(senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!, media: JSQMessageMediaData!) {
        super.init(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: date, media: media)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 

}
```

Now you will have to use this class for all your chat messages.

Next, you will have to create a custom **xib file for your custom cell**.
In that xib you will add a label and image view for the message text and attachment icon.

Now create a **class representing your custom cell**. It will be something as follows -

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var attachmentIcon: UIImage!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Now we have to use this CustomCell in our `JSQMessagesViewController` subclass.

In `viewDidLoad` register your nib with the collection view

```
self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

Now you can finally use your custom cell -

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if message.attachments.count() != 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor()
        cell.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        return cell
    }

    else {
        // Add code here for the normal cell
    }
}
```

This should successfully render your custom cell.

Finally on tapping the custom view cell you can segue to a new VC (dont forget to pass your images data) and show the images appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to send both as one message but you can send them as two messages with a unique custom identifier and then concat them together in your app..
Hope that help

Comment: can u share some code how could i do that. it might be great help. thanks